# Closed and bounded does not mean compact in general

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Suppose in metric space $\Bbb Q$ I consider the subset $\{x\in\Bbb Q | 2<x^2<3\}$. I want to find a open cover for this set which does not have any finite subcover. How to do it ? Hint is enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider a cover consisting of $\Bbb{Q} \cap (-r, r)$ for rationals $r$ with $r < \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: In case one wants to avoid explicit reference to irrational numbers like $\sqrt 3$, a cover consisting of sets of the form $\{x\in\mathbb Q|2<x^2<r\}$ with $r$ rational and less than $3$ would do.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: yes, i also got this solution.